# how to compare 3 options hierarchy value and return boolean the scala way?

Tags: scala, functional-programming

lets say I have this case class:

```
case class Report(id: String, imagesInfo: Option[ImageStatus])
case class ImageStatus(status: Option[String])
```

now, I have Option of Report and I want to know if `report.imagesInfo.status == "ready"`, but as you can see imagesInfo and status are options, and I want to return boolean.

so I tried something like:

```
report.flatMap(_.imagesInfo.flatMap(_.status.map(_ == "ready")))
```

but in case status is not defined this will return None, and I want it to return false...
is there a scala way to do something like this without bunch of isDefine's?

thanks

Comment: What should the behavior be when one of the `Option` values is `None`? Your example already seems to resolve your issue without `isDefine`, you can just toss a `getOrElse(false)` or something to the end.

Comment: @Ethan the behaviour should return false. yes you can use isDefined or getOrElse false but wanted something that is more elegant

Comment: @JohnBigs what is wrong with `getOrElse(false)`? What is more elegant than that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will return true if and only if `report.imagesInfo` is `Some(Some("ready"))`:

```
report.imagesInfo.exists(_.status.contains("ready"))
```

Conversely, this will return true unless `report.imagesInfo` is `Some(Some(x))` and `x` is not `"ready"`:

```
report.imagesInfo.forall(_.status.forall(_ == "ready"))
```

Note that `contains(x)` is equivalent to `exists(_ == x)`, but is generally more performant.